# events doesn't work after the element is dropped in droppable area - jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using Jquery UI and i have implemented drag and drop functionality
I have binded click functionality to each element

But when the element is dropped in droppable area the click functionality doesnt work
Not only click ... none of the functionality binded to element works..

Answer (score 1):

Did you use `.click()` to bind the events or did you use `.on()` ?
Where have you placed the handling of your events ?
Are those ui elements loaded or created after the DOM has been loaded ?
All those things you have to consider because if your elements are added AFTER the DOM has been loaded you have to use `.on("click",function(){})` to bind you event handler to the elements. Because if you have used .click() and the element you are trying to access isn't loaded at this point this doesn't work !

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {

$('#draggableImages img').draggable({    

      cursor: 'move',

      revert: 'invalid',
 
});

$('#img1').click(function() {
  alert("::");
});

$( "#dropbox" ).droppable( {



  drop : handleElementDrop

});

function handleElementDrop(event , ui) {

  var dragElement = ui.draggable;

  alert("Element id is " + dragElement.attr('id'));

}

}
This is my jquery code